# how to change the build parameter of `msbuild` command line

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I currently clean my sln file using

```
Msbuild myproj.sln  /t:clean
```

and then build it using

```
Msbuild myproj.sln
```

Both the above work because my project is set for 32 bit.

My question is how can I incorporate 64bit into the above functions ?

Say I want to build 64 bit what should the command  be then  ? I know the following command simply picks up the one that is set as default in Visual studio

```
Msbuild myproj.sln
```

Comment: You first have to add the x64 configuration, then use /p to select which one you want to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MSBuild myproj.sln /p:Platform=x64
```